# How to secure the app against screen sharing and prevent screen sharing using Google Meet, AnyDesk

Tags: android, flutter, security, screenshot, screen-capture

I am developing an app which shows proprietary content. This requires stopping any possible screen capture, screenshots or screen sharing. In order to prevent screenshots, I used

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);`

But many screen capture apps (like Screen Recorder) and screen sharing apps (like Google Meet, AnyDesk) are ignoring this flag and still allowing screen sharing.

I have used many other banking applications where screen sharing on above apps is not possible (Other sees complete white or black screen whereas the user sharing the screen continues to operate on the app).

How to enforce the security flag or is there any other API call (or packages) which makes this possible?

Any solution in native Android or Flutter is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I am using FLAG_SECURE for preventing the screen sharing and it is working for Google Meet, Anydesk, and Teamviewer.

For voice, using AudioManager i am muting the microphone while the process is running on OnResume and OnStop methods.

```
 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (audioManager.isMicrophoneMute())
        audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
```

Happy Coding...